# Chrome is displaying varied width

Tags: html, css

Ok I have 10 divs which should be all 75px wide with a 1px border making them 77px wide.
I am trying to set the width of `row1` to the minimum required to accomodate the 10 boxes.

My maths is as follows

- 77px * 10 = 770px
- 2px margin right * 9 = 18px
- A total of **788px**

Yet when set the width to 788px, the last box overflows. Upon further inspection I noticed using developer tools that the width of the boxes vary between 77px (3 times) and 78px (7 times).

Why are the boxes not all the same size, as this messes up my maths. I am using Chrome, the code works fine in IE.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/control.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="board">
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.body { font: 12px "helvetica neue", helvetica;
}
.board {
    background: #EBEBE0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 808px;
}
.row1 {
    background: #FFDCDC;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 788px;
}
.box {
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
div.box:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/TMBuy/)

Comment: Did you resetted the defaults first?

Comment: No, how do I do so? I didn't know about defaults at all.

Comment: Check this out http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: @CTravel yes this one is a strange one. It works fine in fiddle and IE browser. But somehow my chrome is messing up the widths of my boxes. When I remove the border 1px and use a background instead, my maths would work as expected.

Comment: @enyce12 mate I have copied 2 of those resets, it doesn't solve the problem of overflowing.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me. Seems like there's something more going on than just the code you posted.

Comment: Are you able to produce a functional basic example in JS Fiddle that reproduces the produce and which you can post a link to here. The boxes could just be solid colour for the purposes of the exercise.

Comment: @ralph.m I have edited my question to show the generated HTML and CSS there is nothing more to my code.

Comment: @pwdst I dont know how to create JS Fiddles, but CTravel fiddle code is exactly the same as my posted code. The issue is with Chrome giving my boxes different widths.

Comment: Strange. In Chrome for Mac there's no issue with that code.

Comment: Windows 7 Chrome 32 works fine.

Comment: All boxes are 75px for me using that CSS and HTML, and the "row" element is 788px. Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Indded, OK in Chrome W7 - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Fhuyt

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: windows 7 chrome 32 @pwdst

Comment: @EltonFrederik Can you look at http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/MFEAe/ and see if it re-produces your problem? Works fine for me Windows 7 x64, Chrome 34.0.1797.2

Comment: @pwdst In the fiddle it works, but when I copy the code and open the page in Chrome, the last box overflows.

Comment: @EltonFrederik Can you 1) Ensure that you have closed the body and html elements (which isn't shown in your code), and if that doesn't work 2) remove the xml:lang and xmlns attributes from your HTML element which look like hangovers from XHTML and certainly aren't in the spec for HTML 5.

Comment: @pwdst I have made sure the body and the html elements are closed. Also I have got rid of the xml:lang attributes. The problem still persists. Can I also note that I have a `header.php` which is generating the header. But since I posted the generated HTML I felt there was no need to mention it, perhaps I should?

Comment: Maybe is the border? Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Comment: Screenshot of what I think is the problem [link] (http://snag.gy/c98oM.jpg) [/link]. Please notice how the boxes have different widths.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez I am sure it is the border, because when I use a background instead, my maths adds up as expected. But as you can see in the screenshot I posted, my boxes have different widths.

Comment: That's weird. Can you check where the CSS is taken from, at the developer tools?

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez it is taken from the correct file. [link] (http://snag.gy/9DLZL.jpg) [link]

Comment: But I also noticed that widths vary even if I don't use the border 1px, the only difference is that it doesn't overflow then.

Comment: Weird, tested the example of @pwdst in Chrome 32.0.1700.76, Windows 7, and seems OK. The only things I can think of are that some other style is interferring, or some default value is causing the issue. The weirdest thing is that doesn't semm to be a pattern of the sizes. What happens if you resize the window before/after loading the page? does the sizes differs?

Comment: When I resize the windows the sizes don't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys after struggling with this code, I resorted to uninstalling Chrome and reinstalling it. Now the problem is fixed.

I want to thank you all for your efforts.

Comment: Please accept your own answer in case someone else has the same problem - it should help indicate what helped in your case more quickly. Answering your own question is actively encouraged on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce the problem either...

I've copied and pasted your code and it seems well to me.
Have you tried to create a blank document (`.html`) and paste the code you've put here to check if this problem also occurs?

Another question is: What is in the javascript file? Can't it be changing anything from your styles? Maybe something like `$(div).css('margin', '10px')` (just for an example).

Comment: No the JS is currently empty. I did create a blank html document, but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you send us a picture of the code running in Chrome with the Developer Tools opened?

Comment: That is unbelievable lol. Did you try to test in anonymous browsing? Just to be sure that this is not a cache problem.

Comment: I don't how to test in anonymous browsing?

Comment: Open Chrome with Ctrl + Shift + N and open your file with it.

Comment: Oh you mean incognito mode. Just did, the problem persists. This one really is strange.

Comment: God, I don't have a clue of what is causing this problem. =( Sorry.

Comment: It is ok.  Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour may occur because of spaces between the div.

Try this:

```
<div class="board">
    <div class="row1"><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"></div><!--
    --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the issue referred to only applies to elements with `display:inline-block`..which is not the case here.